# Bash Autocomplete Ubuntu list all rather than cycle

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete, terminal, tab-completion

On a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install, my terminal tab-complete settings are configured such that the options are cycled through upon the second tab rather than what I am used to (listing all options and only completing what can be determined)

For example, in a directory containing listPixels.html and listPublishers.html, I want the a tab complete from

```
l
```

to simply complete

```
listP
```

and then a second tab should list all possible matches rather than cycling through listPixels.html and listPublishers.html on each subsequent tab.

Comment: Use zsh? ;) It works this way by default, afaik.

Comment: That's definitely a potential future for me.  Luckily, for now, I got the desired behavior out of good ol' Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `menu-complete` turned on. Simply rebind <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `complete`.

```
bind '"\C-i":complete'
```

Comment: Fixed!  Thanks for the quick succinct response!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a setting in your .inputrc.

Use the line:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous On
```